# heroku hibernate query gets no results

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, heroku

I am new to Heroku, but have used Hibernate in the past. I am trying to query my Heroku database but I am getting no result. I KNOW the database table I am querying has one record in it.

I would be very grateful if someone could spot what I have overlooked (after much searching, head-scratching, etc)

Here is my servlet.xml file (Spring)

```
<bean id="dbUrl" class="java.net.URI">
    <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}"/>
    <!-- <constructor-arg value="postgres://hfdovnidtaqsou:hK6uveO4d7nls_ogdrKjsSYzGs@ec2-54-195-243-250.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/db7nnh2r11om9c"/> -->
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
    <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}" p:packagesToScan="com.yomi.*">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.yomi.beans.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
 </bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />
```

And here is my hibernate.cfg

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property> -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="defaultNChar">true</property>
</session-factory>
```

Lastly, here is the class where I am trying to query the database:

```
@Transactional
public class UserTestServiceImpl implements UserTestService {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

/**
 * @param sessionFactory the sessionFactory to set
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> readUsers() {
    // Retrieve session from Hibernate
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    logger.warn("=============== session=" + session + " ================");
    logger.warn("=============== session.isOpen()=" + session.isOpen() + " ================");

    // Create a Hibernate query (HQL)
    Query query = session.createQuery("FROM com.yomi.beans.User");

    List<User> users = query.list();
    logger.info("=======================================users.size():" + users.size());

    return users;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your SQL (after execution) printed on console is correct?

Comment: May be you are missing `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />` before `transactionManager` bean in servlet.xml file

Comment: Hi Amogh - apologies for the delay in getting back to you! I do have the tag you have mentioned above in my servlet.xml file. Do you have any other thoughts on this one? Thank you.

Comment: Figured out the problem...FINALLY!

Comment: In my Entity class, I was referring to: import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity; I changed this to: import javax.persistence.Entity; Lastly, I had to get javassist.util.proxy.methodfilter on the classpath (using Maven). Now my query is working...Phew.